# How to enable OpenGL 2.0 and WebGL on GMA 3150?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, intel-graphics, opengl, webgl

I have a Dell Mini 1012 which has an Intel N450 processor and GMA 3150 integrated graphics card running Ubuntu 10.10. According to Intel's website the graphics card supports OpenGL 2.0.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-reference-guide-to-intel-integrated-graphics/#9

But when I type `glxinfo` in terminal the OpenGL version string gives me the following

```
OpenGL version string: 1.4 Mesa 7.9-devel
```

I have installed the latest drivers but it didn't work. So, how can I enable OpenGL 2.0 on this card?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Install `driconf` from the software center .
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `driconf` and press enter .
3. Change **Enable limited ARB_fragment_shader support on 915/945** from **No** to **Yes** by clicking on the button next to it

Comment: This might solve a problem i was having with 2 dv6700 laptops.

Comment: Thank you but: Dell Inspiron Mini 1012 here as well, Ubuntu 16.04 (times passes by) up-to-date, mpv won't use OpenGL. To enabe OpenGL 2.0 features I also set "Enable stub ARB_occlusion_query support on 915/945" to Yes in the « Deboguage » tab. [Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/696190)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 10.10 should [contain the drivers for the GMA 3150](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/591579). This seems a slightly odd situation, with the Intel website saying:

> Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator 3150 supports OpenGL* 1.5 with Microsoft* Windows* and OpenGL* 2.0 with Linux*

I would suggest you report a bug, by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and entering `ubuntu-bug xserver-xorg-video-intel`. This will automatically attach information about your hardware setup to the bug report. This way the Ubuntu graphics team will get to see your problem and help you solve it.

Comment: [Bug #696190: Intel Drivers for GMA 3150 only supports OpenGL 1.4 instead of 2.0](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/696190)

Comment: yes this is the bug i reported............do please subscribe if you're having the same problem