# Update graphics card driver

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics

From what I can tell, my graphics card driver needs updating (for WebGL support). What is the process to do this?

The details of my graphics card are as follows:

**Adapter Description:** Intel Open Source Technology Center - Mesa DRI Intel(R) Q35 x86/MMX/SSE2
**Vendor ID:** Intel Open Source Technology Center
**Device ID:** Mesa DRI Intel(R) Q35 x86/MMX/SSE2
**Driver Version:** 1.4 Mesa 9.0

I am running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: 12.10 reached end of life a while ago, it's no longer supported.

Comment: Does this mean I can't use any new graphics card driver with it?

Comment: You are free to do whatever you wish, try convincing Intel to release an installer for 12.10. Good luck.

Comment: @Dodo you can still get softwares from old-releases repository but they will be outdated. I will still recommend upgrading to 14.04 for official support.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get more up to date drivers is to upgrade your Ubuntu installation (12.10 - which has reached end of life (EOL) in July 2013) to something more recent.
14.04 is the current "Long Term Support" (LTS) release. I would recommend you to upgrade to that version, unless you require some more "bleeding edge" packages.
I don't think you can upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04, which has also reached EOL in January 2014.
I think your only option is a full reinstall. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) guide may help you if you are new to installing Ubuntu.
Don't forget to backup your data.

Comment: I'm going to try to dual boot Windows 7 or 10 with Ubuntu, so I suppose this would be a good time to upgrade to 14.04 too. Would I lose performance with Ubuntu 14.04, or would the driver upgrade be worth it?

Comment: @Dodo you wont lose performance with ubuntu 14.04, if you are worried about unity eating too much performance try ubuntugnome 14.04 lts.

Comment: IIRC, you should gain some performance. Unity has a bit more polish and optimizations, but you get a more recent GCC (which is faster) and more recent GPU drivers. If anything, 14.04 should be faster than 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

A solution was posted for intel gma 3150 with ubuntu 10.10 [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19607/how-to-enable-opengl-2-0-and-webgl-on-gma-3150). I think it should work on your card too.

Make sure graphics card drivers are installed

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

Enable WebGl and openGl using `driconf`

```
sudo  apt-get install driconf
```

Open `driconf` and turn `Enable limited ARB_fragment_shader support on 915/945` from `No` to `Yes`

Comment: `Enable limited ARB_fragment_shader support on 915/945` was already on `Yes`.

Comment: @Dodo I see, i think only option now is that you should upgrade your distro to 14.04 and then check for webgl support in your graphics drivers, it might be already implemented by defualt in latest ones.

Comment: From what I've found, the newer drivers do provides WebGL support.

Comment: Thats good then, i myself use ubuntu 14.04 and i assure you its much better.